# git key_from_blob and key_read error

Tags: git, ssh

I'm getting the following error when I try to pull from git.

```
$ git pull origin master
key_from_blob: remaining bytes in key blob 266
key_read: type mismatch: encoding error
From github.com:mea36/duca2011/group5
  * branch master -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date
```

but my code isn't being updated.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I know almost nothing of the internals of git, but it might help to indicate what OS you're using, and what version of git (`$ git --version`)

Comment: I get the `key_from_blob: remaining bytes in key blob...` error from using a newer style ssh public key that some systems I work on do not recognize. In particular, a `id_ecdsa.pub:ecdsa-sha2-nistp256` key that ssh-agent forwarding passes through an older firewall machine.

Answer (score 6):

These are messages from SSH when trying to read key files:

```
key_from_blob: remaining bytes in key blob 266
key_read: type mismatch: encoding error
```

Typically you see them on the server when someone has used an invalid key format in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys (server side); however given that they are showing up client side, I'd recommend checking your keys (~/.ssh/*)

You can use ssh-keygen to validate keys:

```
ssh-keygen -B -f id_rsa.pub
```

e.g.

```
$ ssh-keygen -B -f /tmp/foo
2048 xipab-kikup-tanas-pahop-sihoc-lipaz-tusav-dybuf-lubuf-vasob-dyxox /tmp/foo.pub (RSA)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably some problem with how your SSH connection is set up.

But this probably shouldn't affect the pulling. And your code isn't updated, because there is nothing to update. As the last line states, you are already up-to-date.